# Cant start GNS3 due to Python issues

Tags: python

I have installed GNS3 (network emulator) on a Debian-Jessie machine but when i try to start the program i get the bellow error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted
```

Any ides why is this hapenig?

I also took an strace in case that helps:

```
/usr/lib$strace /usr/bin/gns3
execve("/usr/bin/gns3", ["/usr/bin/gns3"], [/* 38 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1115000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe93573f000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=183999, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 183999, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe935712000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0a\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=135744, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2212904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe935301000
mprotect(0x7fe935319000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe935518000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7fe935518000
mmap(0x7fe93551a000, 13352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe93551a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\10\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1697504, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3803552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe934f60000
mprotect(0x7fe9350f7000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe9352f7000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x197000) = 0x7fe9352f7000
mmap(0x7fe9352fd000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe9352fd000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14640, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe935711000
mmap(NULL, 2109680, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe934d5c000
mprotect(0x7fe934d5e000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe934f5e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fe934f5e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105608, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe934b59000
mprotect(0x7fe934b5b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe934d5a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fe934d5a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0;\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=166032, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2261096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe934930000
mprotect(0x7fe934956000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe934b56000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7fe934b56000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=109144, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe935710000
mmap(NULL, 2204200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe934715000
mprotect(0x7fe93472f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe93492e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7fe93492e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0pU\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1067424, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3162344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe934410000
mprotect(0x7fe934514000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe934713000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x103000) = 0x7fe934713000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe93570f000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe93570e000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe93570d000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fe93570e700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe9352f7000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe934713000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe93492e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe934b56000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe934d5a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe934f5e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe935518000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x8fd000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fe935741000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fe935712000, 183999)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fe93570e9d0)         = 30088
set_robust_list(0x7fe93570e9e0, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7fe935306ba0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fe935311ed0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7fe935306c30, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fe935311ed0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1115000
brk(0x1136000)                          = 0x1136000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1668976, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1668976, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe935575000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26258, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26258, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fe935738000
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x7fe9352fc8c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
read(3, "\277\310\6}\261\210\337\236\5\227\353\273\201M\20x\363:\220Q\226H\251>", 24) = 24
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe9343d0000
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe934390000
brk(0x1157000)                          = 0x1157000
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 7), ...}) = 0
readlink("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/python", "python3", 4096) = 7
readlink("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/python3", 0x7fffc1cc4220, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
open("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/pyvenv.cfg", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/pyvenv.cfg", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/Modules/Setup", 0x7fffc1cc51b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/lib/python3.4/os.py", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/lib/python3.4/os.pyc", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/lib/python3.4/os.py", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/lib/python3.4/os.pyc", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/lib/python3.4/os.py", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/lib/python3.4/os.pyc", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/lib/python3.4/os.py", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/lib/python3.4/os.pyc", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/os.pyc", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/os.pyc", 0x7fffc1cc51a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Could not find platform independ"..., 55Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
) = 55
stat("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/pybuilddir.txt", 0x7fffc1cc51b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload", 0x7fffc1cc51b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload", 0x7fffc1cc51b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/gns3/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload", 0x7fffc1cc51b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload", 0x7fffc1cc51b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload", 0x7fffc1cc51b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload", 0x7fffc1cc51b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Could not find platform dependen"..., 58Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
) = 58
write(2, "Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to "..., 57Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
) = 57
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe934350000
brk(0x1178000)                          = 0x1178000
sysinfo({uptime=2240881, loads=[86848, 87776, 71104], totalram=8275865600, freeram=282087424, sharedram=0, bufferram=84557824, totalswap=0, freeswap=0, procs=622, totalhigh=0, freehigh=0, mem_unit=1}) = 0
brk(0x119a000)                          = 0x119a000
sigaltstack({ss_sp=0x1179700, ss_flags=0, ss_size=8192}, NULL) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/python3.4/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu", 0x7fffc1cd62c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu", 0x7fffc1cd5ca0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/lib-dynload", 0x7fffc1cd62c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=36864, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/lib-dynload", 0x7fffc1cd5ca0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Fatal Python error: Py_Initializ"..., 69Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
) = 69
write(2, "ImportError", 11ImportError)             = 11
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "No module named 'encodings'", 27No module named 'encodings') = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
tgkill(30088, 30088, SIGABRT)           = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=30088, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT +++
Aborted
```

I have also tried to set PYTHONHOME as per bellow but still no luck:

```
user@station:~$which python
/usr/bin/python
user@station:~$export PYTHONHOME=/usr/bin
user@station:~$echo $PYTHONHOME
/usr/bin
user@station:~$gns3
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `export PYTHONHOME=/usr/bin`. Python should be installed in `/usr/bin` on Debian.

If not, run `which python` and use the directory that it returns so: `export PYTHONHOME=<directory>`

**Edit**

Also try `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7`.

Before you do though, make sure that directory actually exists. It will vary depending on python version but this should be where modules are stored.

Better yet, append it rather than replacing with:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but teh Fatal Python still persists. I have also updated the original question

Comment: I edited the post. Looks like it's not finding the modules so hopefully that should sort it. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same issue this day. I till now you did not find a solution let me telln you what I did to solve it.

- first, purge your hold gns3 installation depending on your distribution.I'm on debian so I have used the following command :
  $sudo apt-get autoremove --purge gns3*
- second,go to the gns3 official website : https://docs.gns3.com/1QXVIihk7dsOL7Xr7Bmz4zRzTsJ02wklfImGuHwTlaA4/ and follow the installation for you new gns3 version